# Does the following equation imply $u=0$

Tags: calculus, integration, vector-analysis

Hi I am working on a proof and I ended up with this equation:

$$\int_\limits{\partial \Omega}\alpha u ds + \int_\limits{\Omega} u dx = 0$$

where $\alpha >0$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Does this imply that $u=0$? If yes, then help me see why. Thanks!

Comment: The equation seems to be satisfied by $u(x,y)=x$ on the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$, unless I'm misunderstanding.  When you say “where $\alpha > 0$ and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$”, do you mean *some* $\alpha$ and $\Omega$, or *any* $\alpha$ and $\Omega$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I mean "for some".

Comment: OK, then I don't think it's true, given my example: $u=x$, $\alpha = 1$, $\Omega$ is the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang does it?